# jQuery click anywhere in the page except on 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers, click

How can I trigger a function when I click anywhere on my page except on one div (`id=menu_content`) ?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can apply `click` on `body` of document and cancel `click` processing if the `click` event is generated by div with id `menu_content`, This will bind event to single element and saving binding of `click` with every element except `menu_content`

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
       if(evt.target.id == "menu_content")
          return;
       //For descendants of menu_content being clicked, remove this check if you do not want to put constraint on descendants.
       if($(evt.target).closest('#menu_content').length)
          return;             

      //Do processing of click event here for every element except with id menu_content

});
```

Comment: what about descendant childs in the DIV?

Comment: We can use closest to check of source of event has any ancestor with id menu_content like if($(evt.target).closest('#menu_content').length) retrun; check my updated answer.

Comment: Since `closest` begins with the current element, it handles clicking on `menu_content`, as well as clicking on descendents. I think the second `if` is all you need.

Comment: if ($(evt.target).closest('#menu_content').length) {
          return;
}

Somehow bootstrap 3.3 doesn't work for me in a modal window. Cannot find  closest(). Always .length == 0

Answer (score 51):

See the documentation for [jQuery Event Target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). Using the target property of the event object, you can detect where the click originated within the `#menu_content` element and, if so, terminate the click handler early. You will have to use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to handle cases where the click originated in a descendant of `#menu_content`.

```
$(document).click(function(e){

    // Check if click was triggered on or within #menu_content
    if( $(e.target).closest("#menu_content").length > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise
    // trigger your click function
});
```

Answer (score 46):

try this

```
 $('html').click(function() {
 //your stuf
 });

 $('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

you can also use the  [outside events](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-outside-events-plugin)

Comment: This work, but using event.stopPropagation() can have knock on effects on other JS contained within the parent.

Answer (score 12):

I know that this question has been answered, And all the answers are nice.
But I wanted to add my two cents to this question for people who have similar (but not exactly the same) problem.

In a more general way, we can do something like this:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
    if(!$(evt.target).is('#menu_content')) {
        //event handling code
    }
});
```

This way we can handle not only events fired by anything except element with id `menu_content` but also events that are fired by anything except any element that we can select using CSS selectors.

For instance in the following code snippet I am getting events fired by any element except all `<li>` elements which are descendants of div element with id `myNavbar`.

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
    if(!$(evt.target).is('div#myNavbar li')) {
        //event handling code
    }
});
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that this method worked for me just fine, I used .is() and also .closest() with a css selector that had no ID but just some classes thank you

Answer (score 7):

here is what i did. wanted to make sure i could click any of the children in my datepicker without closing it.

```
$('html').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.id == 'menu_content' || $(e.target).parents('#menu_content').length > 0) {
        // clicked menu content or children
    } else {
        // didnt click menu content
    }
});
```

my actual code:

```
$('html').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.id != 'datepicker'
        && $(e.target).parents('#datepicker').length == 0
        && !$(e.target).hasClass('datepicker')
    ) {
        $('#datepicker').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice version including clicks ont children and class, should be the picked answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$(":not(#menu_content)").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Run your function when clicked anywhere except #menu_content
    // Use with caution, 'cause it will prevent clicking on other elements
});

$("#menu_content").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Run when clicked on #menu_content
});
```