# Click anywhere but in the div to close menu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to close a menu when the user clicks anywhere but in it.

I've tried a few options from this question but this is the closest one that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12661833/609630

Essentially this:

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
    // Check if click was triggered on or within #menu_content
    if( $(e.target).closest("#menu_content, #menu-item-2003 a, #menu-item-2003 ul li a").length > 0 ) {
      return false;
    }
    $("#menu-item-2003 ul").slideUp( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

`#menu_content` is the div that opens up and `#menu-item-2003 a` is the link that is clicked to open the menu. `#menu-item-2003 ul li a` are the links deeper within the menu.

I've got a lot going on within `#menu_content`... using the code above has killed the links within it (`#menu-item-2003 ul li a`), how can I make those work again? Apart from that the code works.

Comment: `if (!$(e.target).hasClass('open'))`?

Comment: can you add code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reverse the if so that you don't have to return false:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // Check if click was triggered on or within #menu_content
  if (!$(e.target).closest("#menu_content, #menu-item-2003 a, #menu-item-2003 ul li a").length) {

    $("#menu-item-2003 ul").slideUp("slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  }
});
```